"Via vs Through vs By vs Using"
For the context, this is for the title of a dissertation. In essence, it is called "(Doing investigation) through (property of the object being investigated)". The exact title of my dissertation itself is too technical that sharing it would not help that much, but it is semantically very similar to, for instance, "Predicting imminent military operation [through/by/via/using] the surge in the pizza delivery to the Pentagon".
But I am not really sure if through is the best choice, especially when compared to by, using, or via. I think I've seen via a lot in this context, but some posts (e.g., this one) points out that via shouldn't be used in this sense.
What should be used for the title among these four? Or, could there be better alternative?

I wouldn't use via. It is derived from Latin, and these days is used geographically. "I travelled from A to B via (=by way of) my grand parents' place."

As to the other choices, they all look similar. But you may get a more accurate answer if you post the proposed title in full.

@PeterKirkpatrick Writing my exact title wouldn't be very useful since it is too technical, but semantically this is very similar to, for instance, "Predicting imminent military operation by the surge in the pizza delivery to the Pentagon" (unfortunately I couldn't come up with better sentence).

But that is helpful. What you have written is fine. But you could also say "Using statistical variations in pizza delivery to the Pentagon to predict imminent military operations." By changing the details of the wording, each of your options may become more or less suitable. I wanted to illustrate that context matters.

One option is to rearrange the title, as in Surges in the Delivery of Pizzas to the Pentagon as a Predictor of Imminent Military Operations. Of course, this option may be precluded by some other consideration in your context.

Or, instead of all your proposed prepositions, you could use based on.

Often in academic writing, we're writing for some authority figure like a professor or the editorial board of a journal. In this case, don't you have a dissertation advisor? Shouldn't they be the best person to ask?

Thank you all for the valuable inputs. For now, I think I should explore other options to arrange those words to see if there should be a better way to express this. Also, using or based on seems to be better than using other prepositions.

Compare:

Predicting the length of the growing season by the number of birds' nests

by is commonly used in that context.
